# Getting incorrect answer to formula when adding column to table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table looks like this:

```
     error |  num  |    date    
    -------+-------+------------
       274 | 38431 | 2016-07-01
       389 | 54811 | 2016-07-02
       401 | 54465 | 2016-07-03
```

I want to calculate on which dates the 'error' was more than 1% of the 'num'.

Currently I'm trying to do this with this expression:

```
select date, error, num, (100 * (error / num)) as percentage 
from DD 
limit 3;
```

The result I'm getting is incorrect:

```
        date    | error |  num  | percentage 
    ------------+-------+-------+------------
     2016-07-01 |   274 | 38431 |          0
     2016-07-02 |   389 | 54811 |          0
     2016-07-03 |   401 | 54465 |          0
```

I get the same incorrect result if I take out the 100*.

With the solution below,

```
    select DD.*, (100.0 * error/num) as percentage from DD where (100.0 * error /num) > 1.0
```

I get a correct top row but the rest incorrect:

```
     error |  num  |    date    |      percentage      
    -------+-------+------------+----------------------
    1265 | 54642 | 2016-07-17 |   2.3150689945463197
     274 |   274 | 2016-07-01 | 100.0000000000000000
     389 |   389 | 2016-07-02 | 100.0000000000000000
```

I checked the date 2016-07-01 and it has 274 error but the num is much higher. Why would it work for the top row but not for the rest?

Comment: Did you check the values of error and num? They are equal: 274 and 274, 389 and 389 so you get 100 as percentage.

Comment: Yes, totally right. What I'm not understanding is that in the original table shown at the top, the values for 2016-07-01 are different: 274 and 38431. But when I run this query on it, now they present as the same, giving me that 100% percentage output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `100.0` instead of `100` to avoid integer division:

```
select dd.*, (100.0 * error / num) as percentage
from dd
where (100.0 * error / num) > 1.0;
```

Comment: @topplethepat give me a few mins to check.

Comment: the values of error and num are equal in the data you posted, so you get 100%. There is nothing wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `where` clause with arithmetic:

```
select dd.*
from dd
where error > num / 100;
```

If you want the percentage, be careful about integer division:

```
(error * 100.0 / num)
```